# Difference in MYSQL Master Slave DISK SPACE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am using percona_mysql_5.6, both master and slave are in sync as terms of replication and table wise records are also same. However there is a difference is the disk space consumed. The slave is consuming relatively more space than master. Even the mysql.conf is same for both master and slave. Any idea why this might happen or any leads that i can check?

```
Server            Name           Engine Version Row_format  Rows    Avg Data_length Max Index_length    Data_free
Master            MasterTable       InnoDB  10  Compact 148087092   320 47392686080     0   31006982144 6291456 
Slave(10.52.146.189)    SlaveTable  InnoDB  10  Compact 214554824   476 102218530816    0   40179859456 5242880
```

Comment: Relatively more space, meaning roughly how much more?  5%? 10%? 25%?

Comment: slave consumes around 15% more space than master.

Comment: That looks like 2x (100% more) for data and 1.3x for index.  Quite significant.  ("Rows"  cannot be trusted and "Data_free" is "small" on both.)

Answer (score 1):

The tables on the Primary and the Replica are maintained separately.  All InnoDB tables are B+Trees.

- A block might need splitting on one but not the other.
- A long-running `SELECT` on one might lock rows in such a way that there are more block splits.
- Small blocks may get recombined, but not necessarily with the same frequency, etc, on both machine.
- Were all the same `ALTERs` done on both machines?
- Which columns of `SHOW TABLE STATUS` show the most difference?

If it is a few percent difference, the above things might be the reason.

If it is 50%, something strange is going on; we need more details.  For starters, which one is larger.

Comment: The difference is about 15% i.e. slave consumes 15% more disk space than master.
Alters are done only in master, so it would be the same.
For show table status, Rows,Avg_row_length and Data_length are about 50% higher in slave than master. Could you kindly comment what might be the possible cause for this?

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - Another question -- How did you build the Replica?  Copying the disk at a low level?  mysqldump?  Something else?  Do all the tables have explicit `PRIMARY KEYs`?

Comment: sorry but i did not get your question. I am taking about a cluster with one master and 2 slaves. The slaves replicates the data from master by reading binlogs as part of normal replication process. I am not creating a new slave and dumping the data once.

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - When the Replicas (this is now the preferred term) were originally created, what was the size difference?  That is, did the difference occur _then_?  Or has it gradually grown over time?  Could you actually show me the pair of SHOWs.

Comment: there was a difference in space consumption even when it was originally created but certainly it wasn't this much(was less than 3%). This 15% variance has grown over time. below is the show table status
`Server Name Engine Version Row_format Rows Avg_row_length Data_length Max_data_length Index_length Data_free
Master MasterTable InnoDB 10 Compact 148087092 320 47392686080 0 31006982144 6291456
Slave(10.52.146.189) SlaveTable InnoDB 10 Compact 214554824 476 102218530816 0 40179859456 5242880
     44  53   `

Comment: am not sure how to edit the data format, kindly paste in google sheets.

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - Did you set up replication before inserting any data?  Or did you create the Replica later?